# How to pick the most frequent values (mode) from a raster stack

Tags: r, frequency, raster

I have four layers in a raster stack and want to pick the most frequent value in each cell among the four layers.

Here is the dataset and code:

```
require(raster)
a <- raster(matrix(c(12,11,11, 
                     NA,11,11,
                     11,11,13),nrow=3))

b <- raster(matrix(c(12,12,12,
                     NA,12,12,
                     14,12,13),nrow=3))

c <- raster(matrix(c(13,9,13,
                     NA,13,13,
                     13,NA,13),nrow=3))

d <- raster(matrix(c(10,10,10,
                     NA,10,10,
                     10,10,10),nrow=3))

stk <- stack(a,b,c,d)
```

I wonder if it is possible to do it with code something like?

```
which.freqV <- function(x, ...){
   ???
}

max <- stackApply(stk,1,which.freqV,na.rm=NULL)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had to this in my scripts (calculating the mode of a stack) and found something that works perfectly:

```
  Mode <- function(x) {
    ux <- unique(x)
    ux=ux[!is.na(ux)]
    ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
  }
  layers_mode=calc(stack, fun=Mode)
```

Now, if you want to calculate the frequency of the mode for each cell, use this:

```
  ###calculate proportion of layers that have mode value as measure of uncertainty
  Mode_count <- function(x) {
    ux <- unique(x)    
    ux=ux[!is.na(ux)]
    mode=ux[which.max(tabulate(match(x, ux)))]
    sum(x==mode, na.rm=T)
  }
  layers_mode_freq=calc(stack, fun=Mode_count)
```

Comment: Could you also show me how to get the count for the mode?

Comment: No problem! I am glad it was of help.

Answer (score 3):

You can also consider modal function which also provides some ways to deal with ties.

raster package:

```
# S4 method for Raster
modal(x, ..., ties='random', na.rm=FALSE, freq=FALSE)
```

terra package:

```
# S4 method for SpatRaster
modal(x, ..., ties="first", na.rm=FALSE, filename="", overwrite=FALSE, wopt=list())
```

Answer (score 0):

something very basic

```
a <- freq(stk, merge=TRUE)
a$nt <- rowSums(a[, -1], na.rm = T)
with(a, a[order(nt, decreasing = T), ])
```

Comment: This works for among all the cells, but not for each cell among the layers in the stack.

Comment: ok, i see. you want a new layer with the max among all rasterLayers?